# Bootstrap 3 progress bar not animating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know why my Bootstrap progress bar isn't working?

```
<link type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40%
  </div>
</div>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It's not striped or active.

Mick

Comment: working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/266o9dyd/)

Comment: Very strange. By the way I am using Chrome.

Comment: Works fine for me too, using Chrome.